# Simple Linear Regression: why do we estimate conditionla mean when we can estimate the parameters?

Tags: statistics, regression, parameter-estimation, linear-regression

If we can estimate $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$ and $\sigma^2$ in a simple linear regression model, why do we want to estimate the conditional mean $\beta_0+\beta_1x_0$ at a value $x_0$? I mean we have already all the information that we might possibly need. If I want to estimate the conditional mean I can just substitute the estimates $\hat{b_1}$ and $\hat{b_0}$ to obtain $\hat{y}=\hat{b_0}+\hat{b_1}x_0$ which is indeed the fitted value.

Comment: What is the difference between estimating the conditional mean and the model at $x_0$?

Comment: Because you want to know what the conditional mean likely is?

Comment: @V.V like for example by book says: "We sometimes need to estimate the conditional mean of $\beta_0+\beta_1x_0$ at a value $x_0$ of $X$, which may or may not be one of the values of $X$ in our observed data. A natural estimator of the conditional mean is $\hat{y}_0 \equiv \hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta_1}x_0$"

Comment: .."we then find $$\hat{Y}_0 \sim N\left(\beta_0+\beta_1x_0, \sigma^2h_{00}\right)$$ where $h_{00} = \frac{1}{n}+\frac{(\bar{x}-x_0)^2}{S_{XX}}$." 

So you would think this is the distribution is the distribution of the fitted values right? But no it is not! Indeed after that it says that the fitted values are instead $\hat{y}_I = \hat{b}_0+\hat{b}_1x_i$ and hence their distribution (WHICH IS THE SAME AS BEFORE THO!) is $$\hat{Y}_I \sim N\left(\beta_0+\beta_1x_i, \sigma^2h_{ii}\right)$$

Comment: so all of this makes so much confusion in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish between the prediction of the conditional mean at $x=x_0$ and the prediction of a given point at $x=x_0$.

Recall that your population conditional mean model is $E[Y|X=x]=g(x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x$, thus you are estimating these regression coefficient and then just plug in the $x_0$ and the point estimators of the $\beta$-s, i.e., $\widehat{E[Y|X=x_0]}=\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}x_0$. This estimator depends on a random sample, hence it has a distribution. If you assume that your data generating model is $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, then it is straight forward to show that
$$
\widehat{E[Y|X=x_0]} \sim N(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_0,  \sigma^2 (1/n + (x_0 - \bar{x})^2/S_{xx}).
$$

But what happens if you are interested in the prediction of $Y(x_0)$ itself and not its (conditional) mean? The point estimator is the same, i.e., 
$$
\hat{Y}(x_0)=\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}x_0,
$$
however now you have to consider also the noise term $\epsilon_0$, as such its distributions should be calculated by 
$$
\hat{Y}(x_0)=\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}x_0 + \epsilon_0,
$$
that is 
$$
\hat{Y}(x_0) \sim N(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_0,  \sigma^2 (1+1/n + (x_0 - \bar{x})^2/S_{xx}).
$$
Intuitively, the point estimator does not change because the best "guess" (in the given model) of $\epsilon_0$ value is $0$, however this consideration introduces much more noise to the estimator.